# Verificar a existência de uma string em um arquivo a partir de outro arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho dois arquivos, um é esse:

```
gp2,POL-AES-SHA1,Prop-AES-SHA1
gp2,POL-AES-SHA1-PFS-2,Prop-AES-SHA
POL-3DES-SHA,Prop-3DES-SHA
```

Repare que podem ter 2 ou 3 itens por linha (separados por virgula).

No segundo arquivo tenho:

```
Prop-AES-SHA1,sha1,aes-256-cbc,8
Prop-AES-SHA,sha1,aes-128-cbc,24
POL-3DES-SHA,sha1,3des
IPSEC-AES-256-MD5,md5,aes-256-cbc
IPSEC-AES-256-CBC-SHA256,sha256,aes-256-cbc,8
```

Repare que  pode ter 3 ou 4 itens por linha, também separados por vírgula.

A ideia é que eu pegue o último item de cada linha do primeiro arquivo e procure por ela no segundo arquivo. Se eu encontrar, eu trago todos os itens da linha e crie uma linha misturando itens dos dois arquivos.

Ele só analisa 1 linha e o código para:

```py
file1 = open('file1')
file2 = open('file2')

for i in file1:
    i = i.strip().split(',')
    last_i = i[-1]
    for i2 in file2:
        if last_i in i2:
            print(f'{i} + {i2}')
```

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer apresentar todos que derem 'match', mas esse seu segundo for só esta percorrendo o arquivo uma única vez. Neste caso, ou você armazenaria o conteúdo dele em algum canto, ou teria que percorrê-lo novamente a cada iteração do i.

Desta forma deve resolver seu problema.

```
file1 = open('file1.txt')

for i in file1:
    i = i.strip().split(',')
    last_i = i[-1]

    with open('file2.txt') as file2:
        for j in file2:
            if last_i in j:
                print(f'{i} + {j}')
```

Comment: Gostaria de agradecer imensamente a sua ajuda. Obrigado pelo tok sobre a abertura do segundo arquivo. Funcionou, agora eu consigo ajustar o resultado do print e continuar com o script! Muito obrigado mesmo!